# Using Haystack search with Django Tables 2 views

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

I am trying to use Haystack/Whoosh search with Django Tables 2. The search results should be rendered as table. This is my current view for rendering the tables:

```
def people(request):
    table = PersonTable(Person.objects.filter(pk=1))
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'people.html', {'table': table})
```

Haystack should pass the primary keys of search results to the above view function like so `Person.objects.filter(pk=va1,pk=var2)` so this view function can display the results.

---

I was able to write a working view:

```
def report(request, template='report.html', load_all=True, form_class=ModelSearchForm, searchqueryset=None, context_class=RequestContext, extra_context=None, results_per_page=None):
    table = ''
    query = ''
    results = EmptySearchQuerySet()

    if request.GET.get('q'):
        form = form_class(request.GET, searchqueryset=searchqueryset, load_all=load_all)

        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['q']
            results = form.search()
            pklist = [ r.pk for r in results ]
            table = PersonTable(Person.objects.filter(pk__in=pklist))
            RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    else:
        form = form_class(searchqueryset=searchqueryset, load_all=load_all)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'table': table,
    }

    return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=context_class(request))
```

It works somehow. However, as I'm just a Django beginner, I feel that there is scope for improvement. I posted it here so as to get some useful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that creating your `PersonTable` instance with a `SearchQuerySet` is not an option, you could try passing a list of the `Person` objects from your search.

```
def search(request):
    # Let's say there's some logic here for querying your search engine
    # using Haystack, and `results` is a SearchQuerySet of Person results
    table = PersonTable([result.object for result in results])
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'people.html', {'table': table})
```

Otherwise your problem statement that you need to pass the primary keys of the results to the view function is a little unclear.

Comment: i am getting the following error. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_field'. Any thoughts?